# 2D array in file/program scope

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array, shared-ptr

I need an array which I can access from different methods, I have to allocate this array in main() and then let other functions like foo() get access to this array.

This question helped me with allocating the array: [defining a 2D array with malloc and modifying it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3584705/defining-a-2d-array-with-malloc-and-modifying-it#answer-3584937)
I'm defining the array like this:
`char(*array)[100] = malloc((sizeof *array) * 25200);`
And I'm doing this in main()
I can store 25200 strings in this array an access them by `array[1]`

Is it now possible to access this array from different methods, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this declaration:

```
char (*array)[100] = malloc((sizeof *array) * 25200);
```

You can have a function `foo`:

```
void foo(char array[][100])
{
    array[42][31] = 'A';  // you can access characters elements this way
    strcpy(array[10], "Hello world\n");  // you can copy a string this way
}
```

and you can call `foo` this way:

```
foo(array);
```

Comment: Maybe i should have added i have to malloc it in main()

Comment: @Joelmob Does it change something?

Comment: this is working good but is it possible without needing to have inparameter to foo()

Comment: @Joelmob you can declare `char (*array)[100]` at file scope, `malloc` it in your `main` and directly use it in a `foo` function that takes no parameter; this will work but it is bad style.