# C - Initialize Global 2d Array based upon File

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I would like it create a 2D array based upon values in a file. I am able to do this by making the array local with the following code:

```
int main()
{
    int a = 5; //this is from a file
    int b = 6; //this is from a file
    int (*array2d)[a] = malloc(sizeof(int)*a*b);

    return 0;
}
```

However, I would like array2d to be global. The following doesn't work:

```
int **array2d

int main()
{
    int a = 5; //this is from a file
    int b = 6; //this is from a file
    (*array2d)[a] = malloc(sizeof(int)*a*b);

    return 0;
}
```

Is there any simple way to do this?

Comment: Is your file a text file? What is format of this file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [defining a 2D array with malloc and modifying it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3584705/defining-a-2d-array-with-malloc-and-modifying-it)

Comment: You're missing a semicolon after "**array2d".  It compiles (with warnings) if you put the semicolon on.

Answer (score 1):

Allocation and de-allocation of memory for 2D array you can do with functions:

```cpp
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int ** allocIntArray(int nrows, int ncols)
// allocate memory for 2D array and returns pointer if successful or NULL if failed
{
    int r, c; // rows and cols counters
    int ** parray; // pointer to array
    // allocate memory for rows pointers
    parray = (int **) malloc(nrows * sizeof(int *));
    if( parray == NULL) // check
    {
        return NULL; // error sign
    }
    // allocate memory for each row
    for (r = 0; r < nrows; r++)
    {
        parray[r] = (int*) malloc(ncols * sizeof(int));
        if( parray[r] == NULL ) // check
        {
            // clean memory that was allocated before error
            while(--r >= 0)
            {
                free(parray[r]);
            }
            free(parray);
            return NULL; // error sign
        }
    }
    // return when success 
    return parray;
}

int freeIntArray(int nrows, int **parray)
// frees memory allocated for 2D array and returns 1 if successful or 0 if failed
{
    int r; // rows counter
    if( parray == NULL || nrows < 1)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    // free memory allocated for each row
    for (r = 0; r < nrows; r++)
    {
        if(parray[r] != NULL)
        {
            free(parray[r]);
        }
    }
    // free memory allocated for rows pointers
    free(parray);
    return 1;
}
```

Having this two functions you can create array of any size, e.g.:

```cpp
int ** globArr;
int nrows; // number of rows
int ncols; // number of columns

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    // let's filename is in argv[1]
    if( argc < 2) // we have not filename
    {
        printf("File name must be given as command line argument!\n");
        return 1;  // exit from program
    }
    // when we have filename try to use it
    FILE * f = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    if( f == NULL )  // we cannot read from file
    {
        printf("File %s cannot be read!\n", argv[1]);
        return 2;   // exit from program
    }
    // when we have file openned for reading
    //  we try to read first two numbers and use them as size of array
    if( 2 != fscanf(f, "%d %d", &nrows, &ncols) )   // we cannot read two numbers
    {
        printf("ERROR: Wrong file format!\n");
        return 3;   // exit
    }
    // check that numbers are positive
    if( nrows < 1 || ncols < 1 )
    {
        printf("ERROR: Wrong data size!\n");
        return 4;   // exit
    }
    //  now we can allocate memory
    globArr = allocIntArray(nrows, ncols);
    // check that array allocated
    if(globArr == NULL)
    {
        printf("ERROR: Cannot allocate memory!\n");
        return 5;   // exit
    }
    // and start a loop to read data from file
    int r, c;
    for(r = 0; r < nrows; r++)
    {
       for(c = 0; c < ncols; c++)
       {
          if (feof(f)) // end of file reached 
          {
              printf("ERROR: Unexpected end of file!\n");
              return 6; // exit
          }
          if( 1 != fscanf(f, "%d", &globArr[r][c]) )
          {
              printf("ERROR: Wrong file format!\n");
              return 6; // exit
          }
       }
    }
    fclose(f);
    // Now work with data
    // . . .

    return freeIntArray(nrows, globArr);
}
```

Note: file format can be different from my. I hope, that program will read files in formats

```
2 3
10 20 30
40 50 60
```

or

```
2 3 10 20 30 40 50 60
```

or

```
2
3
10
20
30
40
50
60
```

where 2 and 3 define size of 2d-array