# Issue when copying blocks of memory using memcpy

Tags: c

In my following code, I made `buffer` as a 2D array created using `malloc(r * c * sizeof(double*));`. I want to copy the first 12 elements of `buffer` (i.e. the first 4 rows) into the second one `temp` using `memcpy`.

```
double *buffer = malloc(10 * 3 * sizeof(double*));
double *temp = malloc(4 * 3 * sizeof(double*));

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        memcpy(*(temp+ i*3), *(buffer + i*3), 3 * sizeof(double));
    }
```

I get this error:

```
memcpy(*(temp+ i*3), *(buffer + i*3), 3 * sizeof(double));
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Can someone tell me why?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Surely this is not the entirety of the compiler's diagnostic?

Comment: There is no 2D array, but a 1D array. Any reason you don't use a 2D array, but do the indexing maths by hand?

Comment: And what is the error message? See [ask] and provide a [mcve].

Comment: Can you tell us what the error says?

Comment: This is the error: ` error: passing 'double' to parameter of incompatible type 'const void * `

Comment: -3 votes from the first post !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
double *buffer = malloc(10 * 3 * sizeof(double*));
```

This is wrong, a pointer to `double` wants space for n `double`s (not for n pointers to `double`)

Change to

```
double *buffer = malloc(10 * 3 * sizeof(double));
```

Same for `temp`

> I want to copy the first 12 elements of buffer (i.e. the first 4
>   rows) into the second one temp using memcpy

Use:

```
memcpy(temp, buffer, sizeof(double) * 12);
```

> I get this error:

```
> memcpy(*(temp+ i*3), *(buffer + i*3), 3 * sizeof(double));
>        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

> Can someone tell me why?

`memcpy` wants a pointer (an address) but you are dereferencing the pointer (thus passing a value like `3.14` instead of an address)

Do you want a real 2D array?

In this case you should use

```
double (*buffer)[cols] = malloc(sizeof(*buffer) * rows); /* VLA (since C99) */
```

Take a look to [defining a 2D array with malloc and modifying it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3584705/1606345)

Comment: Or use a 2D array ...

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @Olaf, you are right, but it seems to me that OP wants a flat 2D array (due to the dimensions passed in malloc)

Comment: @AlterMann: You have to pass the dimensions anyway to malloc. I don't think OP **wants** a 1D array. He just might not know there is a better alternative. (anyway, a better way to get the size of an element is `sizeof(* buffer)` instead of repeating the type explicitly. And yes, that works for pointers to VLA, too.

Comment: @Olaf, I mean OP is using (wrong) arithmetic for a flat 2D array and  reserving rows * cols in `malloc`, but you are right, he might not know there is a better alternative, edited

Comment: Yes, the alternative you mentioned is just great. However, it says: `compound array initializer is expected`. Do you know what does this mean

Comment: @KimLee: There is a lot to be found about 2D arrays. Please first do some research on your own. And I already asked you to provide a [mcve]. That's how it works here.