# Memory allocation when casting to a VLA type

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, casting, addressing

I am puzzled by the memory allocation and accesses to a matrix of pointers in an application I am working in.

There is a matrix defined as:

```
typedef double (*foo)[n/m][m][m];
```

Which I understand to be a three-dimensional matrix storing pointers to doubles. The memory allocation for all dimensions is done automatically.

Nonetheless, the following appears:

```
foo bar = (foo) malloc(sizeof(double) * n * n);
```

What exactly is this cast doing?. Furthermore, why do we need to allocate memory for these doubles?. I would think the matrix only contains pointers, which would later be initialized with the memory addresses of doubles declared separately.

Finally, I am, also confused by the way this matrix is accessed during its initialization:

```
bar[i/m][j/m][i%m][j%m] = value;
```

Where i and j are smaller than N. Mainly, I would like to know what the fourth index is adressing.

Thank you so much in advance for your help!

Comment: The cast isn't doing anything. C doesn't require a cast when converting `void*` to another pointer type.

Comment: does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc  . People cast malloc for no logical reason, they just saw someone else do it. The cast has no effect other than to possibly cause suppression of important warnings

Comment: @JG55 This  typedef double (*foo)[n/m][m][m]; is a declaration of an alias for the type pointer to three dimensional array.. It is not "a three-dimensional matrix storing pointers to doubles"

Comment: @M.M Thank you, that is interesting. I am still confused by the allocation itself, though.

Comment: it looks like the array dimensions are [n/m][n/m][m][m]  , when you malloc an array of arrays via pointer to the first element then the first dimension does not form part of the type  . The size could have been written as `sizeof(int [n/m][n/m][m][m])` but the author optimized that to `n*n`

Comment: [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3584705/defining-a-2d-array-with-malloc-and-modifying-it) for example in 2 and 3-D, and then imagine extra 2 dims

Comment: @M.M That example was really helpful. Just to make sure I understand this correctly, foo is defined as a pointer to an [n/m][m][m] array of doubles. Bar is allocated, n*n doubles. This is the size of n/m instances of foo, which makes bar an array of n/m pointers to [n/m][m][m] arrays of doubles. Is this correct?

Comment: This `double (*foo)[n/m][m][m]` creates 1 single pointer `foo` that will be used to point 3 dimensional arrays containing values of type `double`, where the size of each of the 3 dimensions are `n/m`, `m` and `m` respectively, for a total of `(n/m)*m*m = n*m` `double` values in each 3 dimensional array.

Comment: Note that you can use pointer's arithmetic over foo, so if `foo` points to the one 3 dimensional array, then `foo+1` will point to the next 3 dimensional array. So, in pointer notation you would do `(*(foo+1))[0][0][0]` to access the first `double` value of the second 3 dimensional array, and you can rewrite this using array notation as `foo[1][0][0][0]` to do the same thing. So now you can see that by iterating over `foo` you are iterating over the 4th dimension of a 4 dimensional array.

Comment: From the code we see that it was allocated `n*n` `double` values for this 4 dimensional array, so we don't know the size of the forth dimesion, and we could say that the dimensions of the array are something like `[x][n/m][m][m]` where `x` is the unknown size, but we know that this 4 dimensional array will have `n*n` elements, so to find `x` we need to solve `x*(n/m)*m*m = n*n`, therefore `x = n\m`, and the dimensions are `[n/m][n/m][m][m]`.

Comment: I see, thats what I understood from the other comments, but a way better explanation than mine. Would you like to make these comments into an answer? The previous comments were really useful as well. I feel that this explanation is easier to grasp, though.

Comment: Done as requested. `:-)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This `double (*foo)[n/m][m][m]` creates 1 single pointer `foo` that will be used to point to 3 dimensional arrays containing values of type `double`, where the size of each of the 3 dimensions are `n/m`, `m` and `m` respectively, for a total of `(n/m)*m*m = n*m` `double` values in each 3 dimensional array.

Note that you can use pointer's arithmetic over `foo`, so if `foo` points to one 3 dimensional array, then `foo+1` will point to the next 3 dimensional array.

In pointer notation you would do `(*(foo+1))[0][0][0]` to access the first `double` value of the *second* 3 dimensional array, and you can rewrite this using array notation as `foo[1][0][0][0]` to do the same thing. So now you can see that by iterating over `foo` you are iterating over the 4th dimension of a 4 dimensional array.

From the code we see that it allocated `n*n` `double` values for this 4 dimensional array. So, as we don't know the size of the forth dimension, we could say that the dimensions of the array are something like `[x][n/m][m][m]` where `x` is the unknown size. But we do know that this 4 dimensional array will have `n*n` elements, so to find `x` we need to solve `x*(n/m)*m*m = n*n`, therefore `x = n/m`, and the dimensions are `[n/m][n/m][m][m]`.